# Trouble using PNP as a switch

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, pnp, component-selection, electronic-load

I simulated a circuit as shown below and it works as expected when the switch is closed or opened. I later change the 2n2907 to FMMT591A due to availability, continuous collector current and size. I would have simulated same transistor also but the simulation model is not available on proteus. The purpose of transistor is to enable me know battery voltage only when the button is pressed.

Problem:

- one of the led continues to turn without/with pressing of the switch.
- I would have gone for NPN but I already manufactured this board.

[FMMT591A datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/FMMT591A.pdf)

[image: switch is opened here][image: switch closed]

please how can I correct that?

the battery used was 3.7v*3

Comment: For one thing, you need a base resistor for Q1.

Answer (score 1):

You are shorting base to ground to activate the PNP transistor. It's emitter is connected to 11.1 volts via an ammeter (very low impedance). This means, almost certainly that you will destroy the PNP transistor because base-emitter is a diode that gets forward biased when base is taken negative with respect to emitter.

Use a resistor in series with the base to limit base current to less than 200 mA (absolute maximum rating for the FMMT591A) and probably less for the 2N2907.

I'm not saying there are not other problems but I am saying that the lack of a base resistor is a glaring error.

Comment: Yes, I want it to be activated through the ground, I connected a 10k res from the emitter to  base, the purpose of the ammeter is just to display the current through that resistor.

Comment: Then use a series base resistor or swap with a P channel MOSFET. There are no other options here.

Comment: Ok thanks let me do that

Comment: @HGO this is a question and answer site remember. It isn't a progressive learning site where you go off and do a modification and come back with more questions expecting more answers. You have a question area allotted to you and I have an answer area allotted to me. You made a question and I made an answer.